# activemerchant auth.net login error

Tags: authorize.net, activemerchant

I cannot get our auth.net account to work on a new staging server.

The same code, and credentials work find on the current production server, and on my local machine.

The activemerchant config looks like this:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :production #(Rails.env.production? ? :production : :test)
ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.require_verification_value = false
```

I have checked every where i can think of for some config that would be changing staging vs. development vs. production and can find nothing!

I have put logging in to confirm that I am passing the correct login / password to activemerchant.

Answer (score 0):

well this was stupid, apparently another developer when copying the credentials somehow changed a single inner character (from an 8 to a 6) so it was not easily noticable.

I am just posting this answer because I found a great tool that is not very well documented in activemerchant...

add these two lines to an initializer, and you will get a complete log of the low level transactions going on...

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.wiredump_device = File.new(File.join([Rails.root, "log", "paypal.log"]), "a")
ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalGateway.wiredump_device.sync = true
```

You can substitute PaypalGateway with AuthorizeNetCimGateway (or probably whatever gateway you are using)